# Pyglet blit a texture region onto a texture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I would like to create a single texture from multiple smaller texture regions.
What I'm trying is:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.gl as gl

large_texture = pyglet.image.Texture(width=800,
                                     height=600,
                                     target=gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                     id=0)
texture = pyglet.resource.texture("assets/my_image.png")
region = texture.get_region(0, 0, 32, 32)
region_2 = texture.get_region(0, 32, 32, 32)
large_texture.blit_into(region.get_image_data(), x=0, y=0, z=0)
large_texture.blit_into(region_2.get_image_data(), x=0, y=32, z=0)
```

I was expecting that this would place the two texture regions onto the `large_texture`, but instead, I get this error:

```
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid value'
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing, or what (if any) is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually creating a texture right now.

```
large_texture = pyglet.image.Texture(width=800,
                                     height=600,
                                     target=gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                     id=0)
```

Is just declaring a Python object (usually used internally by Pyglet).

The actual texture creation is done in the create method: `large_texture = pyglet.image.Texture.create(width=800, height=600)`

Once you do that, it should work.